# Why is 'this' not volatile?

Tags: c++, symbian

Having spent the last few days debugging a multi-threading where one thread was deleting an object still in use by another I realised that the issue would have been far easier and quicker to diagnose if I could have made 'this' volatile. It would have changed the crash dump on the system (Symbian OS) to something far more informative.

So, is there any reason why it cannot be, or shouldn't be?

Edit:
So there really is no safe way to prevent or check for this scenario. Would it be correct to say that one solution to the accessing of stale class pointers is to have a global variable that holds the pointer, and any functions that are called should be statics that use the global variable as a replacement for 'this'?

```
static TAny* gGlobalPointer = NULL;

#define Harness static_cast<CSomeClass*>(gGlobalPointer);

class CSomeClass : public CBase
    {
public:
    static void DoSomething();

private:
    int iMember;
    };


void CSomeClass::DoSomething()
    {
    if (!Harness)
        {
        return;
        }

    Harness->iMember = 0;
    }
```

So if another thread deleted and NULLed the global pointer it would be caught immediately.

One issue I think with this is that if the compiler cached the value of Harness instead of checking it each time it's used.

Comment: Do you mean that it would have been easier if `this` was volatile, or that it would have been easier if `this` was a pointer-to-volatile? In other words, were you seeing in the crash dump an out-of-date value of `this` (which seems a bit odd since it never changes), or of some data member?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*this* is not a variable, but a constant. You can change the object referenced by *this*, but you can't change the value of *this*. Because constants never change, there is no need to mark them as volatile.

Comment: And by "constant" you mean `T* const` and not `const T*`.

Comment: The answer doesn't really make sense, in C++ terms. `this` is an expression. And `const` expressions can certainly change in C++: `int x = 0; int const* px = &x; std::cout << *px; x = 1; std::cout << *px;`.

Comment: @Mike no he doesn't mean `T* const` he means a `T*` that is not an object. It wouldn't make sense to make `this` `const` either. Well, at least I'm assuming he means. Otherwise his answer doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: Yes, I meant `T* const`. *this* is a const pointer to an object. In some context the object is const as well, then it's `const T* const`, but in either case the pointer itself is const

Comment: @MSalters: The only `const` expression in your example is `*px`. While `px` is a pointer to const (i.e. `int const*`), the pointer itself is not `const` (i.e. neither `int* const` nor `int const* const`) and can be changed. @litb: Why would the `this` pointer *itself* ever not be const? The object pointed to by `this` could be non-const, and frequently is, but when does the `this` pointer ever change over the execution of one of its methods? Even deleting the object only releases its storage; it doesn't change the pointer. Last I checked, assigning to `this` (e.g. `this = 0;`) was illegal.

Comment: @Mike, no `this` does *not* change. So does `0`. Still, `0` is not a `const int`. It makes absolutely no sense to say that it is `const`. *What* is `const`? A value cannot be! When you say `int const a = 0;`, then the object `a` is `const` because it always stores the same value during its life. The value itself (`0`) has no business with it. That's why in C, only lvalue expressions can be `const`.

Comment: ... So you're saying that compilers consider `this` as a pointer literal, rather than a constant variable? I really don't see how `this` resembles `0` more than `a`.  `this` not changing is the argument I'm using to duck-type it as a `T* const`: it looks like one and works like one, so it may as well *be* one.

Comment: @Mike yes `this` is more of a "pointer literal". It's an rvalue anyway. It's an `+a` rather than an `a`. "it looks like one and works like one" not true. Try `&this`. Or try `template<typename T> void f(T&);` calling with `f(this)`. Both would work if `this` were a `T* const` variable.

Comment: So a `T* const` can be an lvalue while `this` cannot? That is the difference? I'd love to see the relevant part of the standard.

Comment: @Mike an expression of `T *const` only ever is an lvalue in C++03. It can't be an rvalue, because rvalues of pointer type are never `const`.

Comment: Well everything has been said. They want me to continue in a chat window. I think I'm not up to that today. I'm going to have a nice cake instead.

Comment: @Mike: 9.3.2 §1 says: "In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a **prvalue** expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a member function of a class `X` is `X*`. If the member function is declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`." (Personal note: in both cases, there is no `const` after the `*`.)

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't help: making a variable volatile means that the compiler will make sure it reads its value from memory each time it's accessed, but the value of `this` doesn't change, even if, from a different context or the same, you delete the object it's pointing at.

Comment: ... because deleting a pointer (specifically, the memory it's pointing to) doesn't magically set the pointer to `0`. The compiler has no way of knowing where all the pointers to an object are.

Answer (score 2):

It can be. Just declare the member function as volatile.

```
struct a
{
    void foo() volatile {}
};
```

Comment: And to answer the actual question, the reason this doesn't happen by default is that you wouldn't be able to pass `this` to a function taking a pointer-to-non-volatile. Same reason `this` isn't a pointer-to-const unless you mark the member function `const`.

Answer (score 2):

volatile wouldn't help you.
It would make the access to a variable volatile, but won't wait for any method to complete.

use smart pointers.

[**shared_ptr**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)

There's also an version in std in newer c++ versions.

Comment: No smart pointers in Symbian C++. I didn't want it to provide synchronization, I wanted it to crash when access a stale pointer.

Comment: @James: Making it volatile won't achieve this, unfortunately.

Comment: shared pointers are templted classes.. you can dowonload it and add to your project

Answer (score 0):

If the object is being read whilst being deleted that is a clear memory error and has nothing to do with volatile.

volatile is intended to stop the compiler from "remembering" the value of a variable in memory that may be changed by a different thread, i.e. prevent the compiler from optimising.

e.g. if your class has a pointer member p and your method is accessing:

```
p->a;
p->b;
```

etc. and p is volatile within "this" so `p->b` could be accessing a different object than it was when it did `p->a`

If p has been destroyed though as "this" was deleted then volatile will not come to your rescue. Presumably you think it will be "nulled" but it won't be.

Incidentally it is also a pretty sound rule that if your destructor locks a mutex in order to protect another thread using the same object, you have an issue. Your destructor may lock due to it removing its own presence from an external object that needs synchronous activity, but not to protect its own members.